# Scaled services and order of events sent as messages (using a broker)

Tags: microservices, message-queue, event, scaling

How would you go about making sure that "events" sent as messages to any sort of broker (Kafka, RabbitMQ etc) from multiple instances of the same service (load balanced) are actually added to the "queue(s)" in a correct order?

So for instance..
Say we have a created an application/service. The service publish the following events/topics as a message to a broker:

- UserCreated
- UserUpdated
- UserRemoved

Now since we have a heavy load on the service, we decide to scale the service to multiple instances.

Some action is taken that ends up creating a UserCreated event, and directly after another action is taken which ends up creating a UserUpdated event.. however both the events are "created" by different instances of our service. Now lets pretend that the service creating the "UserCreated" event is for some reason running slower, so the UserUpdated event is actually added to the queue before the UserCreated event.. is there anyway to prevent this? Any patterns or something that could read up on to understand how to make sure that the order of messages/events actually ends up correctly in the queue in a that has multiple publishers?

Please notice that the above example is just that.. an example, Im fully aware that we could probably "design" our messages in the example above so that UserUpdated sends the fully updated user, and if it doesnt exist we create it.. and if the CreatedUser with the same ID/Username occurs after the UpdatedUser we could just discard that event, but thats not the problem I need to solve. Im just wondering of how to solve the issue of making sure that events are handled by a consumer in the correct order (which I assume required the messages to be published in a correct order?).

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a "fire-and-forget" message pattern in a situation which isn't suitable for fire-and-forget -- i.e. you need strong guarantees of exactly-once delivery and delivery ordering; fire-and-forget is simply the wrong pattern to use in this case.    Ideally choose a different pattern instead (different broker technologies may have alternatives built-in).    For example, RabbitMQ has a feature for Publisher Confirms: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms

Comment: You could research if the Actor pattern is a good fit for your system. It would ensure all actions on a user (or whatever your actual entity is) are handled by the same actor.

Comment: The Theory of Relativity tells you this can't be done.   Seriously.   A way to think about this is to consider what _really happens_ in a _human_ workflow in the same scenario.  Typically either a _single_ human is designated to handle all UserPortfolioModification events - and that human uses his _judgment_ to recognize the situation and deal with it when >1 modifications land in his inbox at the same time - or even simply the same day - or there are >1 humans processing, each can recognize the situation, and they kick it upstairs to someone with _judgment_.  You've got to model this somehow.

Comment: (The only differences between a computer workflow and the same workflow when _human powered_ are 1) speed at which everything happens and _is expected to happen_, and 2) that in the human workflow there are humans in the loop to handle exceptions, _even when the exceptions aren't acknowledged to be possible in the workflow!_  There are _always_ these unacknowledge exceptions that humans _just fix with their knowledge and judgment_ and _that's_ where you run into trouble with computer-_only_ workflows, that don't recognize that _shit happens_ and needs to be _fixed_.  (You're acknowledging it!)

Comment: @BenCottrell, thanks for your comment. Im currently trying to not rely on any "broker specific features".

Comment: @RikD, ty I will look into it :)

Comment: @davidbak, thanks for your comment, Im fully aware of the issue :).. just asking for some best practice advice since Im quite sure I cant be the first one to be having multiple services publishing and consuming the same "topics" for an entity. (Scaled pub and sub services).

Comment: I don't think you can publish messages in "the correct order" from separate machines.  I don't think you can expect the _queue_ mechanism to resolve it: it doesn't have the brains or the context.  I think you need an intermediary service that fixes this problem (out of order messages) according to the semantics you desire and accept that it will introduce latency too. But I don't have any references for you on typical ways (much less _easy_ ways) this is  accomplished, hence: no answer from me, just comments.

Comment: @davidbak As I understood it, the separate services are only load balancers generating messages and aren't the original event sources?     I assume (perhaps wrongly?)  that the original source who creates a user (maybe an administrator sitting in front of a GUI?) is the same as the original source who updates that user so the original source would be able to wait for a confirmation  (so the ordering would need to happen at source and not in the load balancing).    Otherwise I agree it's not possible and I can't even make sense of a requirement for "ordered" events from independent sources.

Comment: @Inx51 everything you do (even fire-and-forget) will use Broker-specific features.   However message patterns aren't broker-specific; the point is to focus on choosing the right message pattern rather than attempting to fit an inappropriate message pattern to a problem.      Even if you implement the message pattern yourself (For example, using a pair of request-response messages), the point is that you can relay acknowledgement/confirmation to the original source which generated the events (i.e. who/wherever makes the decision to create a user, update a user, etc)

Comment: @BenCottrell - OP says "multiple instances of the same service" and "we decide to scale the service to multiple instances" - he definitely has multiple copies of the same service, my interpretation is users connect to some copy or another and start playing with user records (in his scenario given, which is probably not really his actual system).

Comment: The "basic" idea is to create a service which allows other clients to "mutate" an entity.
So Create entity X, Replace entity X, Remove entity X, Update entity X. For each of these "commands" I would like to fire an event. (for instance EntityCreated as "topic" and some data thats valid for the event, like for instance the ID of the entity)
Now.. this event would then be broadcasted to which ever other service thats currently listning/subscribes to that event/topic... However.. the order of the messages might be crucial for the subing service.

Comment: The pub-service might also scale, so basically we could have 1 pub service, or 100.. we might have 1 sub, or 100. However.. only one pub-service would create the event..
So for instance if we had incoming HTTP requests with a load balancer, the load balancer would make sure that the requests hits one pub-service.. but the event(s) generated might be consumed by multiple sub-services and the order might or might not matter (its up to the service itself to decide, but the "option" to "get" orderd messages is required.. even if that involves that the service it self has to handle the ordering)

Comment: @BenCottrell, fully aware that at some point things get broker-specific. But by not relying on features of the broker itself and instead make sure that for instance "ordering" of messages is infact a part of the message itself Im no longer "forced" to use broker X since its the only one with feature X. Which also allows me to be more "flexible" in the choice of broker and (hopefully) more future proof to move to another broker if so needed. But as mentioned, yes, at some point I will need to actually use a broker, and then it gets broker specific (for instance with configs etc).

Comment: If someone who has connected to a particular instance of your service starts issuing events against _one entity that noone else connected to another service is using_ then that can be done with queues: the subscribers will get events in order.  Most (all?) queuing systems have a mode where events from a _particular_ publisher will be transmitted to subscribers in order.  The problem is if from _two different publishers_ there are events against the same entity: those will be interleaved arbitrarily, no way to fix that, there's no global clock.

Comment: Although - that _does_ remind me: There _is_ a concept in distributed systems of a _global distributed clock_.  The work started with Lamport, I believe (as did nearly all great ideas in distributed computing!), and has been greatly studied since then.  But these are methods _outside_ the queuing system (and are quite expensive besides).

Answer (score 1):

I would not, instead I would ensure they are processed in the correct order.

This is much easier, you just listen to the queue and put out of order messages aside until you find the missing earlier message then process them in order.

Do this with an intermediary "routing" message processor. Which picks up off the incoming queue and routes to "process now" or "messages on subject X that need to wait for an earlier message" queues.

Unfortunately this router can't be stateless as you need to keep track of the message groups to some extent. So it can become a bottleneck if you need to order many messages over long periods of time.

Comment: Also introduces latency, unavoidably (else how could you even determine the second message to arrive should have been first without holding the first to arrive).

Comment: I guess you could argue whether that latency was "introduced" by the solution, or by the requirement to process in order

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these service instances share the same database, you can use the outbox pattern in combination with a transaction isolation level that protects you from all your possible race conditions. If you place the "UserCreated" event persistence on your outbox within the same transaction than the user creation itself, you can warrant the correct order of the messages written to the outbox, regardless of which service instance added the message.

Please keep in mind that this doesn't deal with the hypothetical problem of the message consumer receiving the messages in different order, only in-order message delivery to the broker.